# Сохранение ключей в регистре при деинсталяции (WiX Toolset)

Tags: wix

Делаю инсталлер. При установке программы в регистре в некоторых ключах делаются изменения (они перезаписываются с новыми значениями). Как сохранить эти ключи при деинсталляции программы?

Answer (score 1):

В инсталляторе вынеси запись ключей в отдельный компонент и установи для этого компонента свойство `Permanent="yes"`. Пример:

```
<Component Id="PermanentRegValues" Permanent="yes">
    <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" 
                   Key='REG_PATH' 
                   Name='Value' Type='string' 
                   Value='Это значение останется навсегда'/>
</Component>
```

В этом случае компонент не будет удаляться при удалении программы, и, соответственно, не будут удаляться и ключи.